# Software - SNAP and other things

Tags: software-installation, snap-store

Sorry folks......

I'm stuck between a rock and hard place.

I have the Arduino IDE v 1.8.19 installed.
By SNAP I believe.  Not sure and I'll explain later.

This version is OLD and it was suggested I upgrade to Version 2.x of the IDE.
It can co-exist with the other one.
I downloaded it, (zip format), extracted it, CD into the directory, checked the `permissions` (executable) and ran/run it.

I kind of like it but there is/are a bunch of questions that have since arisen:
Looking on SNAP it says I have the IDE installed.

(as per SNAP)

[image: The IDE I have installed per SNAP]

There isn't any "update" option.  Not that I wanted to update it initially.
So, now I want to use the newer version (2.x) why won't/can't SNAP show me an update?

Moving on, I have the extracted ZIP file's directory with the *executable*.
Now I want to make it the main one.
Fair enough.
But I'm confused to WHERE to put it.

As is now it is in `Downloads/arduino-ide_nightly-20231006_Linux_64bit/` with all the associated files/directories included.
Which I'm guessing is not a good place to have it.

This is an official release (not from some dodgy site) so I am lost for understanding why this is happening to me.

What is the *correct* (to call it) place where I should put it?

Now, the other spanner in the works:
It was mentioned to me to edit the `settings` file to allow me to use an external editor.
But there is no option available.
If I open the OLDER IDE, and go to the same place (menu option) I get that and there are other/different/more things available.
But NOT in/on the new one.
Is this a problem with that program or the O/S?

That other thing I mentioned:
A while back I was trying to find libraries and I found a `library` directory in some weird (obscure?) directory to which I had NO PERMISSION to do anything.
Even if I used `sudo` and entered the password.
Yet, I also have a `library` directory which is used in my `Documents/arduino/library` directory.
I know it is used, because that's where there are a lot of libraries I use.
The other directory was put there when I installed the IDE.

Which again raises the question for me:
WHY DID THIS HAPPEN?
(semi rhetorical I guess.)

Now where I am stuck is I want to move on from 1.8.19 and move to the new one.
I've got it working but *where* the file (and associated stuff) is is not practical.
Where am I supposed to put all these files?
Do I keep them in this directory and put the whole lot *else where*?
(where?)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll answer each query in order

1. Snap Packages are created separately from a software's release and they may not be made by the software's developer. Each time some software is updated the snap package must also be updated so people can get the latest version of the software through Snap. You can see on the [SnapCrafter's website](https://snapcraft.io/arduino) that there has not been an update to the Arduino IDE snap since December 2022, which is why when you installed the Snap you got an outdated version of the software. You won't be able to get the Arduino IDE at the latest version with Snap until the owner of this Snap Package updates it. This happens with most package managers. They make installation easier and in the case of APT they will be tested for your release of Ubuntu; but typically to get the latest version of any software you have to go directly to [their website and use only the official packages offered](https://www.arduino.cc/en/software).
2. Regarding where to put software can be argued for hours, but I would recommend putting the files in /opt and creating a symlink to /usr/bin. Do the following.

   1. Uninstall the Snap `sudo snap remove arduino`
   2. Create the directory in /opt
      `sudo mkdir -p /opt/arduino-ide`
   3. Copy the unzipped contents into there:
      `sudo cp -r ~/Downloads/arduino-ide_nightly-20231006_Linux_64bit/* /opt/arduino-ide/`
   4. Create a symlink of the binary into /usr/bin. Doing this means the Arduino binary will be available to run from the terminal without referencing the entire file-path, i.e. you can run `arduino-ide` to open it.
      `sudo ln -s /opt/arduino-ide/arduino-ide /usr/bin/`
   5. Finally, in order to get a nice launcher-tile in the applications tray, we have to create a [`.desktop`](https://help.gnome.org/admin//system-admin-guide/2.32/menustructure-desktopentry.html.en) file and place it in `~/.local/share/applications/`

      1. Create the file and open it with a text editor:
         `gedit ~/.local/share/applications/arduino-ide.desktop`
      2. Paste in the following:

      ```
      [Desktop Entry]
      Name=Arduino IDE
      Exec=/opt/arduino-ide/arduino-ide
      Terminal=false
      Type=Application
      Icon=/opt/arduino-ide/arduino.png
      Comment=Arduino IDE
      Categories=Development;
      ```

      Save and close the file.
      3. Download the icon and save it in /opt:
      `sudo wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/arduino/arduino-ide/main/electron-app/resources/icons/512x512.png -O /opt/arduino-ide/arduino.png`

      You're done

   **However**, Aruduino IDE has an official AppImage which is like an all-in-one binary distribution and because it's official it's using the latest version. While Ubuntu right now doesn't have brilliant integration of AppImages, if you install the [AppImageLauncher](https://github.com/TheAssassin/AppImageLauncher) application it will automatically move AppImages into a suitable location and create .desktop entries to make launching them easier (Adding entries into the applications tray etc.)

   1. Run these commands to install AppImageLauncher:

   ```
   sudo apt install software-properties-common
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:appimagelauncher-team/stable
   sudo apt update
   sudo apt install appimagelauncher
   ```

   2. Download the [AppImage of ArduinoIDE](https://downloads.arduino.cc/arduino-ide/nightly/arduino-ide_nightly-latest_Linux_64bit.AppImage)
   3. Double-click the ArduinoIDE AppImage file, it will bring up the AppImageLauncher prompt which asks whether you want to run Just Once or Integrate and Run.
      [image: Screenshot of the AppImageLauncher Desktop Integration window.]
   4. Choose Integrate and Run, it will be moved into `~/Applications` and an entry into the applications tray will be created to make it easy to launch again next time.
      [image: Arduino IDE in the applications tray]
      This method also makes it much easier to update in future, simply right-click and uninstall Arduino-IDE from the applications tray, then download the latest AppImage from the website and integrate it again.
3. It looks like ArduionoIDE 2.0 has been completely reworked since v1.8 so it should be expected that the settings are different and files may not be in the same places or exist at all. The `preferences.txt` no longer exists, if you're following a guide on how to change the IDE you may need to find one that is made specifically for version 2.0. However, the `settings.json` file is in `~/.arduinoIDE/settings.json` which might be what you need.
4. The Read Only library directory you found is probably in `/snap/arduino/current/libraries/`. Snap packages are *containerised* for security reasons, this is a feature of Snap in that it separates application directories from each-other and stores them all in individual Read Only locations. How exactly this is managed can change, and Snaps (when built correctly) should expose alternative methods of editing these files when required, in this case it looks like you found a second editable location inside your Documents which is normal. It looks like Arduino 2.0 has a built-in Library manager so you should now use that instead of modifying the files directly I think. Access it from `Tools > Manager Libraries...`.

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply.

Comment: Glad to have helped :)